# How to call $products index in favorite product tpl

Tags: arrays, controller, smarty, product, prestashop-1.6

I am using PrestaShop 1.6.0.9, and I want to use product index in favorite product tpl file as it is using in `product-list.tpl` for example:

```
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
```

I know to accomplish this i need to modify PHP and controller class but i need to know how to do this.

Comment: Seriously, I cannot understand your `foreach` loop.

Comment: I need to get all product attributes like price, quantity, category etc in favorite product. How can i achieve that.

Comment: Do you mean `favoriteproducts-account.tpl`?

Comment: yes in favoriteproducts-account.tpl file.